# How to add HMR to Rollup with Svelte?

Tags: svelte, rollup, svelte-3, hot-module-replacement

I am using Svelte and Rollup for my application. I used [official Svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) before it was archived.

This template uses `rollup-plugin-livereload` which reloads whole page on every code change.

I want my code to run without page refreshes. It takes 8 to 10 seconds every time the code changes. Because of this development is super slow.

UPD: And another reason why I use Rollup rather then Vite is because [Vite doesn't support gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1242).

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a direct answer to your question (How to add HMR to rollup+svelte) but*
I suggest you moving from Rollup (which I guess just can't provide you HMR because it's simply a bundler) to Vite using `npm init vite` and then selecting `svelte` as [suggested in README.md](https://github.com/sveltejs/template#this-repo-is-no-longer-maintained-consider-using-npm-init-vite-and-selecting-the-svelte-option-or--if-you-want-a-full-fledged-app-framework-and-dont-mind-using-pre-10-software--use-sveltekit-the-official-application-framework-for-svelte) of legacy template which you used. Rollup was created to bundle your files, it's not a development server which you would like to use. You can learn more about vite here: [vitejs.dev](https://vitejs.dev/).

After cloning template using command above you can migrate your codebase to the new tooling environment which should fit requirements you described in your question.

**UPD:** **Today bundler should not be used as development tool** due to development speed (especially on low-cost devices). But if you really need HMR in rollup, you can take a look at [Nollup](https://github.com/PepsRyuu/nollup). This is the only thing I can suggest you.

I have no idea what RPC thing is, but I can see it's popular, that means you are not alone with your issue. If it can't be used with Vite directly, I am sure you can use it in SvelteKit somehow. I guess when you started development your project SvelteKit was too young, but it's already [released as 1.0](https://svelte.dev/blog/announcing-sveltekit-1.0) today. You can take a look at [agrism/grpc-web-svelte](https://github.com/agrism/grpc-web-svelte), [icflorescu/trpc-sveltekit](https://github.com/icflorescu/trpc-sveltekit), [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/vtewao/trpc_sveltekit_handson_first_impressions/), and so on.. You got my idea.

Comment: Thanlks fro your answer. I am using [grpc-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-web) library which does not work on vite. So i needed HMR to work with rollup.

Comment: @sagar007 Oh.. So that was the reason why you won't use Vite. I have updated my answer, could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin for exactly this purpose. It works perfectly so far and you can check out the code at [rollup-plugin-reloadsite](https://github.com/mugendi/rollup-plugin-reloadsite).